# Getting childnodes starting with a lesser value with XQuery

Tags: xml, xquery, basex

I would like to write an XQuery expression to get all childnodes starting with a childnode with a value which is lesser than the value of the previous childnode and ending with the very last childnode. So for the example below I would like to obtain childnodes with value 1 and 2:

```
<node>
  <childnode>
    <value>4</value>
  </childnode>
  <childnode>
    <value>8</value>
  </childnode>
  <childnode>
    <value>1</value>
  </childnode>
  <childnode>
    <value>2</value>
  </childnode>
</node>
```

What is the most elegant solution in XQuery 3.1 for doing that?

Best regards

Comment: Please share what you already tried to do, i.e. your XQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `tumbling window` clause allows expressing that.

> XQuery in BaseX

```
xquery version "3.1";

declare context item := document {
<node>
  <childnode>
    <value>4</value>
  </childnode>
  <childnode>
    <value>8</value>
  </childnode>
  <childnode>
    <value>1</value>
  </childnode>
  <childnode>
    <value>2</value>
  </childnode>
</node>
};

<root>
{
  for tumbling window $w in /node/childnode
  start $s previous $p when xs:decimal($s/value) lt xs:decimal($p/value)
  return $w
}
</root>
```

> Output

```
<root>
  <childnode>
    <value>1</value>
  </childnode>
  <childnode>
    <value>2</value>
  </childnode>
</root>
```

Comment: Good answer, +1 from my side!

Comment: Tumbling window! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
<node>
  <childnode>
    <value>4</value>
  </childnode>
  <childnode>
    <value>8</value>
  </childnode>
  <childnode>
    <value>1</value>
  </childnode>
  <childnode>
    <value>2</value>
  </childnode>
</node>
 /childnode[value lt preceding-sibling::childnode[1]/value][1]
   /(self::childnode|following-sibling::childnode)
```